# Elegant way to raise events in Update() that are received over the network

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, event-handling

I'm writing a Unity3D game which gets networking events from an external source. The actual network read operations are in their own thread.

When I read some item from the network, I want a Monobehaviour to call some function using that item as an argument in the next `Update()` call. Here's how I make that happen right now (just pseudocode for simplicity)

**The Network Thread**

```
OtherScript script;
while true {
    Thing thing = Network.read()
    script.queue.put(thing);
}
```

**The Monobehaviour (OtherScript)**

```
SynchronizedQueue<Thing> queue;
void Update() {
    while !queue.isEmpty() {
        useThing(queue.pop())
    }
}
```

This definitely works, but my problem is that I'm subscribing to 20+ different types of things, each of which has its own queue and its own "callback" function, resulting in a lot of boilerplate.

Is there some sort of built in mechanism which automates this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems to be in your question. You could use an event instead.

**The Network Thread**

```
public static event EventHandler<NetworkArg>RaiseNetwork;
protected void OnNetwork(NetworkArg arg)
{
     if(RaiseNetwork != null) { RaiseNetwork(this, arg); }
}
while true {
    Thing thing = Network.read()
    RaiseNetwork(new NetworkArg(thing));
}
```

**NetworkArg class**

```
public class NetworkArg : System.EventArgs
{
    public Thing thing { get; private set;}
    public NetworkArg(Thing thing){ this.thing = thing; }
}
```

**The Monobehaviour (OtherScript)**

```
void Start()
{
    NetworkThread.RaiseNetwork += UseThing;
}
private void UseThing (object sender, NetworkArg arg){ }
```

Comment: Looks really good, but does this guarantee that the event will be raised during Update()? Or at least at another time that's legal for a monobehaviour to run without introducing race conditions

Comment: if you need it to be called in a specifc MB callback, then set a flag in the listener and process in the callback.

Comment: I think that's functionally similar to my current approach. I guess what I'm wondering is whether the Unity folks engineered a better solution that doesn't require so much boilerplate

Comment: If you using the Unet system then SyncVar may be something close.

Comment: Afraid not, just raw sockets. I think it's possible what I'm looking for just doesn't exist.

Comment: Well I realize if you need the info over network then ws or socket.io may be your best choice. It would also leverage the broadcasting to the server instead of client. NetworkThread would happen on server and broadcasts to connected users when needed.